# Adding raster values to polygon layer attribute table using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, attribute-table

I'm using ArcMap 10.8.1.

I have a polygon layer of 400m circles, and a raster layer with values from 0-12. I want to identify the highest value from the raster within each 400m circle and record it as a field in the polygon layer's attribute table.

How can I do this?

Comment: Use the zonal stats as table tool extracting maximum value, then join table back to polygon layer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the add surface information tool in the 3d Analyst Toolbox. Under Output Property select Z_MAX.